# How to generate a html report in Protractror,

Tags: angularjs, protractor

**I have tried this in my config file***

```
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

 // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
       },


  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['Enter-description-in-resources-spec.js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1100000
  }

onPrepare: function() {

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
         baseDirectory: '/tmp/screenshots'
      }));
   }

};
```

**but I got a error and I'm unable to understand it**

```
throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after **JasmineNodeOpts**, please correct and pass your reporter in onPrepare function:

```
var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
dest: 'target/screenshots',
filename: 'my-report.html'
});

exports.config = {
directConnect: true,

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome'
   },


// Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
framework: 'jasmine',

// Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
// protractor is called.
specs: ['Enter-description-in-resources-spec.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
 jasmineNodeOpts: {
showColors: true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 1100000
},

 onPrepare: function() {

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter); // Pass the reporter here which you have defined earlier.
 }

 };
```

Comment: i tried it but it's not working still getting the same error

Comment: There seems to be a issue with your Reporter config, why are you creating a reporter again in onPrepare if you defined it already. You just have pass it, please see the config i have pasted which should work fine!

Comment: are you using jasmine 2?

Comment: no,,,,,, just resolve my issue but now the folder that i have save my html file is not visible after running the test cases